# Relationship between the major Indexes and the SPDR Sectors

Tags: index, indexes

Here is what I know (and correct me if I summarize incorrectly):

- There are 4+ main Indexes -- S&P 500, Russell 2000, NASDAQ, and DOW Jones (among others?)
- There are 11 sectors called "SPDRs" or "spiders" that have names like XLC, XRI, XLRE, etc.
- [based on what this site shows,](https://www.sectorspdr.com/sectorspdr/tools/sector-tracker) it seems like these 11 sectors fall under the S&P 500 Index specifically

My question is: does the Russell, NASDAQ, and DOW have their OWN sectors that are not the same as these?

OR -- Are all of these sectors partially weighted in EACH index?

Is there a website that displays this hierarchy of indexes, sectors, and stocks very clearly?

Comment: Both S&P and FTSE Russell have classified each of the stocks in their indexes into 11 similarly named sectors. Nevertheless since the classifications are done independently by the two companies it is possible that some stock (say Apple) is classified differently by these two. S&P's classification system is called GICS, FTSE Russell has defined ICB, you could define your own if you wanted to (as people used to do in the old days).

Comment: Nasdaq is not really an index provider but an exchange. They don't have a Sector classification AFAIK.

Comment: @noob2 okay.. thank you for the information. I guess it's a bit more complicated than i thought!

Comment: SPDR and the associated tickers are just the [ETFs](https://www.etf.com/XLC#overview) replicating the SPX and its sectors, not the sector name themselves (which are GICS classified as @noob2 already mentioned.